# Freezing Dashboard Grid Column headers and rows on the grid reports

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Does anyone know how to make the grid reports you create with the 2010 dashboard designer freeze column and row headers?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried jQuery approach?
If you could find the exact TR tag then you can make it read-only.

If you need additional info on this please let me know, so that I can share the jQuery for the same.